# Docker service failing to start container with error : exec: "java": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: java, docker

While running docker service, its failing to start container, and the `docker service ps <service_name> --no-trunc` is giving following error:

```
starting container failed: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "java": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Following is the Dockerfile that I am using

```
FROM custom_java_image
WORKDIR /root/
COPY target/*.jar /root/myfile.jar
EXPOSE 8443
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/root/myfile.jar"]
```

Comment: `custom_java_image` does not have `java` binary on the path

Comment: ...what is in `custom_java_image`?  Can you `docker run --rm custom_java_image java -version` successfully?

Comment: This command properly returns `java` version